# using LINQ-to-SQL in vb.net with multiple select statement

Tags: linq-to-sql, vb.net-2010

I'm very new to vb.net and LINQ to SQL.
I have been trying the whole day to do this but it doesn't seem to work at all. all your help is highly appreciated.

I have a table named **users** which contains 4 columns

```
+---------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| user_id | user_name | user_password | user_stopped |
+---------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
|       1 | admin     | admin         | false        |
|       2 | user2     | 2             | false        |
|       3 | user3     | 3             | true         |
+---------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
```

I have a from with three textboxes "txtuserid" & "textusername" & "txtuserpassword" and a button name "login"

1) on the "on_click" event of the "login" button , I have this query

```
Dim query = From check In Me.MydatabaseDataSet.users
            Where check.user_id = Me.txtuserid.Text
            Select check.user_name, check.user_password, check.user_stopped
```

I want to do something like this:

```
if query.check.user_stopped= true then
   msgbox("this user has no permission")
else
    me.txtusername.text= query.user_name
    if me.txtuserID.text= query.check.user_id and 
       me.txtuserpassword.text= query.check.user_password then
       me.hide()
       form2.show()
    end if
end if
```

I have been trying for hours but nothing seems to work at all. 
I'm using VB.net 2010 with SQL database.

All your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact Linq is really simple.

```
Dim id as Integer
integer.TryParse(Me.txtuserid.Text, id) 
Dim query = From check In Me.MydatabaseDataSet.users
            Where check.user_id = id
            Select check
```

Would simply return all users with a given Id (Me.txtuserid.Text - converted to integer, it is an integer, right?).

If you specifically want 3 columns:

```
Dim query = From check In Me.MydatabaseDataSet.users
            Where check.user_id = id
            Select New With {check.user_name, check.user_password, check.user_stopped}
```

But keep in mind, this version is returning anonymous type where previous one returns User type.

If you think about it, user_id is a primary key (unique). Thus you don't need to get back a "collection" as the above "query", you simply need a single User:

```
Dim user = Me.MydatabaseDataSet.users.SingleOrDefault(Function(check) check.user_id = id)
```

If that ID exists than the user has properties of that user (typed data), else NULL.

This one matches to code that you later want to execute:

```
if user is not nothing
       msgbox("unknown user")
else
    if user.user_stopped= true then
       msgbox("this user has no permission")
    else
        me.txtusername.text= user.user_name
        if me.txtuserID.text= user.user_id and 
           me.txtuserpassword.text= user.user_password then
           me.hide()
           form2.show()
        end if
    end if
end if
```

Note: I assume this is just for hobby testing purposes, in real world you would never want to store plain text passwords.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. could you  also please let me know how to evaluate if the user_stopped= true and how to check if txtusername and txtpassword equal to user_name and user_password returned by the LINQ query to show the second form. Thank you again.

Comment: @kurrapicazoldik, sorry I don't understand what you mean. You mean something different than the code at bottom ? (edited yours)

Comment: Oh I didn't check null condition there , maybe that is what you are telling.

Comment: I'm trying to devolop a custom tax application for my work. I'm sure I will be needing your help during the first few phases of the app until I get to know the basics. Search through the internet for hours didn't do me any good the first time. Again, Thank you very very much.